# Need to send DTMF codes after phone is dialed in Twillio / Python

Tags: python, dtmf

I am new to Twillio and Python,

trying to build my first script, idea:

Call number, wait 2 seconds, send number 1, wait 2 seconds send number 2

On real phone it can be done using ',' when saved in phonebook

my existing script:

```
call = client.calls.create(
                        twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                        to='+14155551212',
                        from_='+15017122661'
                    )

print(call.sid)
```

if I change it to  `to='+14155551212,,,,,1,,,,,11,,,11',`

gives me an error

Please advice

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

twiml has two verbs `<pause>`, which is pretty self-explanatory, and `<number>` which has the action `sendDigits` which will send the digits DTMF code.  It would be much better for the program to integrate these into twiml rather than trying to change the way you are dialing.

Comment: Hello Paul! Thank you for a tip, would you mind share exact wording / code for twiml ? My default twiml looks like this but I guess this is for incoming calls 'code'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Say>Test</Say>
</Response>'code'